# Angular JS conflict with Jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, widget

I am developing a widget using Angular.

I have an `index.html` file and `script.js` file. From the index.html i included the `script.js` file.

The `scripts.js` file is checking the Angular is already loaded or not. If the Angular is not loaded then latest `Angular.min.js` (tried 1.3.14 version) is dynamically appended to the head tag. And on success of Angular load I created angular module like `angular.module("widgetApp", [])`. This is working fine.

But if I included a `jQuery` js (tried <2 and >2 versions) file from index.html just before the `script.js`, then it makes script errors from angular library.

This is the error I got: `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.12/$injector/modulerr?p0=myWidgetApp&p1=Err…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.12%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A381)`.

I have created a plunker for this issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/JHDrGakpuLWpfeauUs1V?p=preview

Any body have any idea on this issue?

Comment: Can you add the relevant content from `scripts.js` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seemed to be a problem with the order of `ng-app` being applied before the module was created.
It's probably better/more reliable to manually bootstrap instead of adding the `ng-app` attribute:

```
angular.bootstrap(document, ['myWidgetApp'])
```

This way you can control when the bootstrap happens, which should only be after everything is loaded (in `scriptLoadHandler`)

Here's the working plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/DKlh5S1ZisxIwluXeJ38?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your valuable solution. Leme try by integrating this in my project.