# How to fix Angular JS Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having a problem with Angular JS receiving an error

```
jquery.js:7993 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module application due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'application' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

my controller is **controller.js** as follows

```
angular.module('application') .controller( 'controller', [ '$scope', 'service', '$uibModal', '$uibModalStack','$rootScope', function($scope, service, $uibModal, $uibModalStack,$rootScope) {}]);
```

and my service is **service.js** as follows

```
angular.module('application').service('service',
        [ '$resource', function($resource) {
            var requstService = $resource('test', {}, {

            });
            return requstService;
        } ]);
```

when i load the view page it running perfectly but when i click again on site link it showing above error.Please help.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28985031/angular-js-conflict-with-jquery)

Comment: Have you loaded your js files in the correct order?

Comment: Yes i am loading scripts file dynamically.when i click First time then it working but not on second click.

Comment: Just to give context to all the 'add `[]`' answers. If you omit the `[]` Angular will try to search for a module that you already created by the name and return it. Adding the array instructs Angular you want to create the module. It's one of the most common causes for your error, hence the answers.

Comment: @ste2425 Not working

Answer (score 1):

Your controller should be,

```
angular.module('siteApplication',[]) .controller( 'siteController', [ '$scope', 'siteService', '$uibModal', '$uibModalStack','$rootScope', function($scope, siteService, $uibModal, $uibModalStack,$rootScope) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `[]` in your controller to create module like this.

```
angular.module('moduleName', [])
```

and use this in your html page like `ng-app="moduleName"`

and add dependency js file related to `$uibModal`.

Comment: please add js file related to $uibModal.

Answer (score 0):

your module is missing `[]`
your controller should be like:

```
angular.module('siteApplication',[])
```

also did you not paste the ending part of the controller i.e `} ]);`
on purpose ?